# Flutter Web: Convert ui.Image to ImageProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm using `CustomPainter` to draw something to a `canvas`.

Later I want to display that drawing in an `Image` widget (which takes an image parameter of type `ImageProvider<Object>`).

After some research I have found out a way to get there in basically two steps:

1. create a `ui.Image` object from the canvas drawing
2. convert that `ui.Image` to an `ImageProvider` that can be passed to an `Image` widget

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bitmap/bitmap.dart';

class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    //drawing some stuff here
    //canvas.drawRect(...);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;

  Future<ui.Image> getImage() {
    final ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    try {
      //500 x 500 pixels
      paint(Canvas(recorder), const Size(500, 500));
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }

    final ui.Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final img = picture.toImage(500, 500);
    return img;
  }

  static Future<ImageProvider> getProviderFromImage(ui.Image image) async {
    final ByteData? bytedata = await image.toByteData();
    if (bytedata == null) {
      return Future.error("some error msg");
    }

    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.fromHeadless(
        image.width, image.height, bytedata.buffer.asUint8List());
    final Uint8List headedIntList = bitmap.buildHeaded();
    return MemoryImage(headedIntList);
  }
}
```

The problem here is that this won't work for *Flutter Web* because the [bitmap package](https://pub.dev/packages/bitmap) does not have web support.

I already tried converting the `ByteData` to `Uint8List` without the *bitmap package*:

```
  static Future<ImageProvider> getProviderFromImage(ui.Image image) async {
    final ByteData? bytedata = await image.toByteData();
    if (bytedata == null) {
      return Future.error("some error msg");
    }
 
    final Uint8List headedIntList =
        Uint8List.view(bytedata.buffer);  
    return MemoryImage(headedIntList);
  }
```

But the resulting `ImageProvider` won't be accepted by the `Image` widget:

> ════════ Exception caught by image resource service
> ════════════════════════════ The following ImageCodecException was
> thrown resolving an image codec: Failed to decode image data. Image
> source: encoded image bytes

Comment: Your original approach is likely faster than compressing to PNG (but worth comparing). `bitmap` uses `ffi` for image manipulation, but sticking a BMP header on doesn't need that. Drill down into the code of `bitmap.buildHeaded();` and you may find it just does simple simple manipulation you can extract.

Comment: Looks like you just need this class https://github.com/bluefireteam/bitmap/blob/master/lib/src/bitmap.dart - it even seems to have a helper that extracts from an image provider. It doesn't seem to have any dependencies that would make it incompatible with web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach actually works if the `format` parameter of `toByteData()` is passed:

```
  static Future<ImageProvider> getProviderFromImage(ui.Image image) async {
    final ByteData? bytedata = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    if (bytedata == null) {
      return Future.error("some error msg");
    }
 
    final Uint8List headedIntList =
        Uint8List.view(bytedata.buffer);  
    return MemoryImage(headedIntList);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small `RawImageProvider` that takes an already loaded [dart:ui.Image](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) and wraps it inside an [ImageProvider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html) so it can be used on places where an image provider is expected.

Note that you can also directly display a [dart:ui.Image](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) using the [RawImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawImage-class.html) widget.

### Usage

```
Image(
  // pass your dart:ui.Image here
  image: RawImageProvider( yourImage ),
  ...
);
```

### RawImageProvider Code

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

/// Wraps an already loaded image into an [ImageProvider].
class RawImageProvider extends ImageProvider<RawImageProvider> {
  final Image _image;

  RawImageProvider(this._image);

  @override
  // clone is important here, otherwise the RawImageProvider might dispose the original image
  ImageStreamCompleter load(key, decode) => _RawImageStreamCompleter(_image.clone());

  @override
  Future<RawImageProvider> obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    return SynchronousFuture<RawImageProvider>(this);
  }
}

class _RawImageStreamCompleter extends ImageStreamCompleter {
  _RawImageStreamCompleter(Image image) {
    setImage(ImageInfo(image: image));
  }
}
```